# Automatic comments by Community

Tags: discussion, comments, closed-questions, moderation, new-users

There seem to be automatically generated comments by "Community".

As an example, [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/417745/14094) by a new user has

> *Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.* – [Community](https://mathoverflow.net/users/-1/community) Bot

Just for completion, the question is

> [A little background on Thompson groups] *There is a concept of Higman-Thompson groups which are generalization of Thompson group. I would like to know the definition of Higman-Thompson groups. Thank you in advance!*

My rough understanding is that such messages occur in some case involving new users, and poorly received questions (currently 1 downvote 1 closing vote 0 upvote). Is the algorithm to generate such comments known? Are such automatic comments useful in any way? Are they supervised by moderators?

[Indeed in the present case, this generic message is not really useful (I remember seeing other cases where it wasn't either). What OP asks is very clear, but somewhat open-ended (which is OK in some cases), and definitely shows no effort by OP (since OP asks for a definition that is available at many places). ]

Comment: As you can see, this specific question was [in the first question review queue](https://mathoverflow.net/review/first-questions/161081). If you try for yourself, you can see that this text is one of the options you can choose in that review: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjNzd.png

Comment: Related feature announcement: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/241919). As per Martin's comment, the comments by the Community bot are not automatic, but they are just being delegated from the (human) reviewers: "*Reviewers are encouraged to leave comments for the post-author, but now they can also choose from a few options of canned feedback which will appear as a comment from the Community account.*"

Answer (score 4):

At least this part of the question has been basically answered in the comments:

> Is the algorithm to generate such comments known?

Some of the comments explaining where these comments come from have been deleted in the meantime - but they can still be seen [in the MathOverflow chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/conversation/comments-by-the-community-user-from-the-first-questions-review-queue).

I.e., these comments are not actually "automatically generated" by the software - they are chosen by MathOverflow users who review the questions in these two review queues.

---

**Short answer:**

These comments come from the [first questions](https://mathoverflow.net/review/first-questions) and the [first answers](https://mathoverflow.net/review/first-answers) [review queue](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/review-system/info). When reviewing in these queues, the user gets an option to leave a comment. It is possible to write your own comment or use one of the predefined options (canned feedback}. It is also possible to leave the comment signed by the [Community user](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/community-user/info) or post it as your own comment.

Here is a screenshot taken from the First questions review queue.

[image: screenshot from the first questions review queue]

---

More details can be found here:

- The announcement from August 2021: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013). (Which says that the first posts review queue, that used to exist, is now split to First questions and First answers.)
- Several feature requests concerning these new review queues (and the comments from the review) have been posted as answers in the above thread and also in other posts on Meta Stack Exchange, such as: [Add link to help center in the canned First question comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374987) or [Indicate or limit character capacity in custom comment textarea of review modal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375111).
- There is this post on Meta Stack Overflow: [Formatting feedback for First Answers review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415828). (I did not find posts on other per-site-metas where some sites have requested customization of the canned comments.)

Comment: The answer is CW - feel free to edit it further if needed. (But I'll stress that this is intended to answer only the part about the functionality - i.e., how and when these comments are created by the software. Whether they are useful and how they can be changed is certainly for discussion - let's leave this to other answers, if some users are willing to share their thoughts on this.)

Comment: Alternatively, if the OP decides to update the question and include the relevant information (explaining that these comments come from the review queues) - I won't object to deleting this answer if it is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. Certainly it's better include the answer in an answer (as you did) than in the question.